# How to return a single cell value from a dataset?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataset which i am selecting a row and a column (without using col method) and i retrieve the relative cell value using the following code :

```
 List<Row> selectedRow = dataset.filter(col("id").equalTo(index)).select(nameOfColumn).collectAsList();
```

and then `selectedRow .get(0).get(0)`

I put the selected row into a list of rows (selectedRow which is composed only by one row)

Is there a more elegant way to do that while by-passing `col(columnName)` method to get the column and then the cell value of the selected row from the dataset ?

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `collectAsList` you could use `head`.

Comment: @Werner Yes thanks ! but could you check my next question ?